Determining the Number of Possible Sign Combinations for $n$ Elements
I want to know all the possibilities for a combination of $n$ elements when taking their signs into consideration.
If $n=1$, meaning that we consider the set $\{a_1\}$, there are $N=2$ options:
$$
a_1 > 0 \quad \text{or} \quad a_1 < 0.
$$
If $n=2$, meaning that we consider the set $\{a_1, a_2\}$, there are $N=4$ options:
$$
(a_1 > 0, a_2 > 0), \quad (a_1 < 0, a_2 < 0), \quad (a_1 < 0, a_2 > 0), \quad (a_1 > 0, a_2 < 0).
$$
Is it true that the number of possibilities is $2^n$?

What about if $a_n=0$? If elements can be zero, you have 3 possibilities for each element ($+, -, 0$), and so $3^n$ total cases. If they cannot, it's just $2^n$.

The short answer is: yes!
There are many ways to show this. For a simple analogy consider a simple urn model. Let the number of balls in the urn be $b$. Since you only care about the signs of the $a_i$, in your case $b=2$ (i.e. one ball is labeled -1 and the other is labeled 1). Your are drawing the balls with replacement, i.e. every time you draw a ball you put it back into the urn.
The numbers of ways you can draw $n$ balls from the urn with replacement is $b^n$. In your case, as you suggest, that comes out to $2^n$.
As a previous comment mentioned: you should think about how you want to deal with 0s. In that case $b=3$, which you could plug into the above formula.
